# How to hide/remove options from a side navigation bar based upon user's role? (best practice)

Tags: php, html, css, tinybutstrong

Environment:  PHP/5.5.6

I have got 2 *.html files for side navigation bars defined, one for Role A and one for Role B. There are similiarties between the two and I would sort of like to combine the similarities into one single file, and include the different options based upon role, when a user logs in.

ie:

- Side Nav Bar has 5 options. Option 1 to Option 5.
- Role A has access to Option 1 - Option 4.
- Role B has access to Option 1 - Option 3 and Option 5.

Currently a user logs in, the file that is called is based upon the user's role, but if roles are expanded than each role will require another file. I don't like this approach cause it's bloating, and sometimes a simple change causes changes in multiple files - not fun and not nice.

1. I have considered placing all options in one file and using the CSS
   display:block or :none along with javascript / jquery to display the
   required features to the user. I don't know if this is the best
   approach. Even though the items are not visible the html to these
   options is visible if one views the source code.
2. I also considered TinyButStrong to add elements to list based upon a
       user's role, and the element would be contained in it's own file. I
       am not sure on how this approach would work cause I am looking
       merging(adding) a single item on the side nav menu. Currently I am
       using TBS to include whole divs and not single elements as detailed
       below.

ie side nav option html file contains

```
<li><a href="/page5">Option 5</a></li>  <!-- another file would have option 4 -->
```

base side nav *html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/page1">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page2">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page3">Option 3</a></li>
    <!-- insert Option 5 or Option 4 here -->
</ul>
```

Which approach is the best or is there another way in which I should approach this? If an approach above is not good why?

Hope that someone can help and/or guide me at this point in time.

Comment: did you see 'magnet' [at the manual](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_field_prm) (scroll a bit down) it says " A magnet tag is kept as is when the field has a value, and is deleted when the field is null or empty string"

Comment: How are you currently including the while divs in the template using parameter "file" ? Do you have a template loaded from a file ?

Answer (score 1):

Move the contents of the *.html files in to one *.php file, and then exclude / include menu items in that one file using the roles outlined using php.

For example:

```
<?php
    if (roles->getUserRole(reports)) { echo "<li><a href='/page5'>Reports</a></li>"; }
?>
```

Of course you would use your HTML menu structure and permissions class etc, the above is just an example....

Comment: I like this, cause it sounds like what I want. I am hesistating because this project doesn't have any examples of php mixed with html. Currently TBS is being used to merge the menu by pointing directly the *.html. Could this be done the same way by directly pointing at the path of the php file?

Comment: I have no experience with TinyButStrong, but I would assume you can load a .php file as easily as a html file. If you are using a templating engine (I missed that when I read your post) then you can build your HTML menu structure completely within the calling PHP file, and then pass it to the HTML file to display using whatever TBS uses as template variables...

Comment: Well it worked sort of but for some reason the end of my echo the </li> got removed, which caused the the trailing "}?> to also be displayed next to the menu item. Might of been due to a javascript function that the href was calling defined inside the link. The change displayed to me that this is going to require a massive overhaul on the site and so until I have time to look at it all, I will. I was hoping that it would of been much easier fix, but I under estimated the number of locations that this is being referenced when being built.